# Asp.net Mvc receives a complex object as a list of key/value pair array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have two asp.net mvc apps that am trying to get to communicate with each other by sending a complex serialized object from one of the app to the other.

But when the data reaches the other end, the object comes in as a list of array of key-value pair. Below are the details of the what am trying to send/recieve.

**Here is the code that am using to send the json object**

```
 using (var hc = new HttpClient())
            {
                hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(Media);

                var dict = new Dictionary<string, DejaVuObject> {{"Entity", obj}};

                var strinified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(strinified, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response =  await hc.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
                return response;
            }
```

**The receiving method signature**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RecieveEntity(Dictionary<string, object> post)
```

**Here is what am sending**

```
{
 "Main Service ID": "1",
      "Node ID": "",
      "Parameters": [
         {
            "Name": "firstname",
            "Validation": {
               "Entity": 0,
               "EntityListFilter": "",
               "IsNotEditable": false,
               "IsPrimaryIdentifier": false,
               "IsRequired": true,
               "IsUnique": false,
               "Parameter Format": 0,
               "ParameterMode": ""
            }
         }
      ],
      "CustomEvents": [
         {
            "Description": "event description",
            "Message": "new message",
            "MilestoneCondition": "milestone information.",
            "Name": "new message",
            "TheFields": []
         }
      ],
      "Processings String": "Action failed.[TN01-31:Action failed]"
}
```

**Here is what am receiving**

```
{
 "Processings String": "Action failed.[TC01-71:Action failed while processing the request.]::Action succeeded.[TC01-54:Processing this command was successful.]",
   "Parameters": "[Name, Firstname][Validation, ][Key, 2e431711-2ba9-40ef-985e-dbfa8c13a932][isrequired, True][fieldname, ][Name, Lastname][Validation, ][Key, be4de2d6-d39e-44fa-8f31-b4b0964f82da]",
   "CustomEvents": "[Description, Processing this command was successful][Message, Action suceeded][MilestoneCondition, When command processing suceeds.][Name, Action suceeded][TheFields, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Dynamic.DejaVuObject]]",
   "Main Service ID": "1"
}
```

If you look properly in what comes into the other system, you will find that the of most of the inner object is an array of key/value pair instead of ordinary array of objects that was sent. What am I doing wrong, and how do i go about correcting it?

Comment: What's the receiving method signature ?

Comment: @krishna check out my edit.

Comment: change dictionary to dynamic in both ends like `Dictionary<string,dynamic>`

Comment: Another option would be to define a view model in both the sending and receiving apps and let model binding do its magic.  (Unless of course you need the endpoint to be more dynamic than that...)

Comment: @Krishna The problem is that i cant really change the definition of the second app, as its already being used by other systems without breaking something, what I can only do is figure out how, to make the first app send what the other app can de-serialize properly as its already working in other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Its the fact that you're using a dictionary type to receive the content. At the point the data packet is sent from the app1 its as per your definition.  So updating app1 isn't going to help you.

As @Krishna has suggested update the signature to use dynamic, or you can extend your current app2 method to deal with the new interface.

Do you have an example of the data packet from one of the existing integrated apps?